# Adding Global Using Directive in blazor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

> The type or namespace name 'XXX' does not exist in the namespace 'MyClassLibrary.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?). **The error refer to this BlazorProject\MyPager.azor.g.cs**

**I got this error after this scenario:**

1. Created a file of type `.cs` inside my **"Blazor project"** and I added all my global directives by using keyword `global` inside this file.
2. Changed some namespaces in my **"Class library"**

**Structure of the project:**

1. Blazor-serve-side project using the class library
2. Class library.

When I go the page , I can't see any error, the error just in VS, I tried to clean the solution, rebuild, closing VS and reopen but it doesn't solve the problem. I am using VS22 and .Net6.

***Note***
I have also in my blazor project `_Imports.razor` file

Comment: CLose VS and delete the `bin` and `obj` folders from the project(s) - if you still see problems, do the same but also delete the `.vs` folder(s)

Comment: @MisterMagoo, Thanks. I think also that we can't combine `_Import.razor` and `global` ??

Comment: According to the issue tracked here, looks like global usings don't apply to Razor: [Resolve issues with global usings in Razor compiler #7539](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/7539)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@MisterMagoo, Thanks a lot.
what you said works fine, plus that I have to repeat the same namespaces with `global directive` file and also in `_Imports.razor` file, so the soultion:

- In `GlobalUsings.cs`:

  ```
  global using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
  global using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
  ```
- In `_Imports.razor` if you need the same namespaces in your razor pages, then you have to repeat them.

  ```
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the scope of "global using" isn't truly global. It's the current compilation, which typically means the current *project* (**not** the current *solution*). If you want to use this feature in two different projects in your solution (a Blazor Server project and a Class Library in your case, for example) you will need to create "global using" statements in both projects.