# How can i define gloabal C# code classes in ASP.NET Blazor which functions can be called from each partial class of the related razor pages?

Tags: c#, class, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor application where I program the code of each razor page in the related xxx.razor.cs Class in C#. I have the case that I use common functions in this C# codes. So instead of repeating the common functions in each class, I want to define a common class, and then call the function from each class. How can I do that? I have tried it like in a C# desktop application but it didn't work.

```
Commonclass test = new Commonclass();
test.CommonFunction();
```

Comment: Please define "didn't work"

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why but after trying for hours I see my error always just when I have posted my question. I had copied the common class from another directory. I forgot to correct the namespace. After correcting it worked. Sorry that i have taken your time.

Comment: it depends what you are trying to do and how you are doing it.

Comment: Before you get too far note that Blazor supports dependency injection out of the box. I'd create a `scoped` or `singleton` service depending on your needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Global Using Directive in blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72227448/adding-global-using-directive-in-blazor)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after trying for hours I see my error always just when I have posted my question. I had copied the common class from another directory. I forgot to correct the namespace. After correcting it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted way to do this is dependency injection. Either a `scoped` or `singleton` service.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Commonclass>();
```

**Razor Page**

```
[Inject] Commonclass test { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    test.CommonFunction();
}
```